# stripe subscription from registeration date of the month with initial fee

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to do stripe monthly subscription with these conditions

monthly charge 29.99 dollars

when registration is done in the middle of the month installation price of 50.00 dollars will be added with subscription price.

For example, user registered October 29th

79.99 dollars should be paid at that timing. Installation Fees + Subscription Fees

29.99 us dollar subscription is charge at the same date of next month
how can I configure this? I want to know the configuration for stripe in codeigniter php

```
$price = \Stripe\Price::create([
      'unit_amount' => 29.99*100,
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'recurring' => ['interval' => 'month'],
      'product' => 'Monthly Plan Home Internet',
    ]);

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'email' => $email,
        'source'  => $token,
    ]);

    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
        "customer" => $customer->id,
        "currency" => $currency,
        "add_invoice_items"=>array(
             array(
            "price"=>$price->id
        ),
        ),
        "items" => array(
            array(
                "price" => "29.99"
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Follow The Following Code

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
 'email' => $email,
 'source'  => $token,
  ]);
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
        "customer" => $customer->id,
        "currency" => $currency,
        "add_invoice_items"=>array(
             array(
            "price"=>"price_1LyBtEIhiBmLLX1CMotP6b2z" //first month payment with installation fees
        ),
        ),
        "items" => array(
            array(
                "price" => "price_1LyC2vIhiBmLLX1ChID4GBZu" //monthly payment
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Subscription you can use [`add_invoice_items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-add_invoice_items) to add a one-time Price to the first Invoice of the Subscription only.

That will be charged in addition to the recurring price you set in [`items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-items), and the one-time Price will not show up on subsequent Invoices.

Comment: Can You Please Provide Some Examples. I am very new to it. Thanks